# Subtitles for multilingual DVD audio tracks in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I've been using VLC to watch DVDs for a while, but many of them have portions in different languages to the main audio-track. For example, there are numerous Spanish-language scenes in Breaking Bad, and Dothraki/Valyrian scenes in Game of Thrones, both of which to me are entirely incomprehensible.

Playing the DVD through Windows Media Player or a regular DVD player displays the subtitles for the foreign language portions only. With VLC, it appears to be all-or-nothing on the subtitle front.

I have searched for automatic subtitles in VLC, but only seem to find information for downloading subtitle tracks. If someone has a solution, or can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You using the latest version of VLC?